# How to call child model controller by using best_in_place gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, best-in-place

I have a `ActiveRecord::Base` class `Box` that `has_many` `Card`s model.

There are some cards in box `show.html.erb` like this:

#### views/boxes/show.html.erb

```
...
<% @cards.each do |card| %>
<%= best_in_place card, :front %>
<% end %>
...
```

I want to edit value by using `best_in_place`, but it send request to `BoxesController` not to `CardsController` and ends up with error `AbstractController::ActionNotFound - The action 'update' could not be found for BoxesController:`.

How can I specify a controller with `best_in_place`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can specify a path like this:

```
<%= best_in_place detail, :price, :display_as => :mk_bal, :classes => 'price_bind', :path => purchase_detail_path(@purchase, detail)%>
```

Comment: According to the warning `:path` is deprecated, so I use `:url`. Thanks anyway!